# Need some help converting java org.json to jackson

Tags: java, jackson, org.json

Newb here trying to create an addon in java, it took me a very long time to get this to work in org.json and was hoping someone can help me convert it to jackson as I've encountered some issues with memory when using org.json (downloading a 30mb file ends up using 800mb ram, and reaches and stays at 3gb before it stops increasing for repeat downloads)

Any tips on how else I can reduce memory usage would also be welcome. (app is at 65mb when loaded, then reaches 800mb once downloaded and 1.2gb when the json file is created, then it increments by 200-300mb every time it downloads again)

```
public void getAHdata() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;

    try {
        URL obj = new URL(getAHURL());
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray objarray = myResponse.getJSONArray("auctions"); //it has one other array but I only need auctions: http://auction-api-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/auction-data/54866b3dbf5983e2599b240798cf2938/auctions.json

        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("TN.json")) {
            file.write(objarray.toString());
            file.close();
        }
        objarray = null; //dont think this helped with memory
        response = null;
        myResponse = null;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } 
}
```

Comment: You have to keep old data on next download??

Comment: You use a lot of memory by the way you've written it: First you read into a String, then parse the whole thing. Would be better to directly parse the InputStream! And maybe you could also parse object by object instead of the whole stream.

Comment: @Simmant the old data is saved in the file TN.json, which is used by other methods on demand (so I dont, or I'm hoping its not, keep the json data in memory). That file will then get replaced my the next download again.